# ORACLE syntax: What is this called?

Tags: oracle

I saw a Oracle statement, like this:

```
SELECT sn.launch_cd, sb.launch_cd FROM standard_nuke sn, standard_ballistic sb WHERE country = 'US';
```

The "standard_nuke sn, standard_ballstic sb" part appears to take the form of

```
[table_name] [name]
```

What is this called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a table alias.  It's not specific to Oracle; most databases support this, or a notion of it.

Aliases offer a more convenient way to refer to a table, or allow you to specify which table's column you're referring to.

For instance, if `standard_nuke` and `standard_ballistic` both had a column `country`, you could specifiy that you meant your `WHERE` clause to concern itself with `standard_nuke`'s country by this SQL:

```
SELECT sn.launch_cd, sb.launch_cd 
FROM standard_nuke sn, standard_ballistic sb
WHERE sn.country = 'US';
```

Comment: But I thought aliases take the form of "[table_name] AS [name]"?

Comment: It *might* take that form.  My recollection from Oracle databases is that I never needed the `AS` keyword.  MySQL/SQLite/Postgres don't need it, or it's optional, in the context of a table alias.

Comment: @Makoto, in Oracle SQL table aliases cannot be specified with `AS`; paradoxically, *column* aliases may be specified with `AS`.

Comment: That's right.  It's coming back to me now... That's why I don't recall using `AS`.  Thanks for pointing that out.